# Выравнивание тектового поля в отчете Access 2007

Tags: excel, ms-access, report

В отчете базы данных *Access 2007* выводится поле Мемо (комментарий) с большим текстом (более 255 символов). Инструментарий позволяет выровнять этот текст по левому или правому краю, или же центру. А надо сделать "по ширине", как это умеет *Excel*. Опция в Окне свойств поля "*Выравнивание текста/Подбор*" не подходит, т.к. текст становится очень уж страшным. 
Спасибо, если кто-нибудь поможет.

Comment: Спасибо всем, мне удалось это сделать: Надо в таблице у поля Мемо поставить Текст РТФ, потом в отчете: Данные - текст РТФ, В Макете - Выравниваение - Подбор, Контекст - слева направо.

Comment: Только теперь она межстрочные интервалы не устанавливает...

Comment: @YVK, устанавливает. хоть свой для каждой строки.